# Hive, Beeline: Peer indicated failure: GSS initiate failed

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm launching beeline to test Sentry using account added in Kerberos:

```
beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://IP:10000/;principal=test_table/domain_name@HADOOP.COM"
```

but

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
    scan complete in 3ms
    Connecting to jdbc:hive2://IP:10000/;principal=test_table/domain_name@HADOOP.COM
    Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://IP:10000/;principal=test_table/domain_name@HADOOP.COM: Peer indicated failure: GSS initiate failed (state=08S01,code=0)
    Beeline version 1.1.0-cdh5.5.0 by Apache Hive
```

However, if I connect with account hive, it works!

```
 beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://IP:10000/;principal=hive/domain_name@HADOOP.COM"
```

Why could this happen? By the way, I used `kinit` to the account on my client.

Comment: The "principal" shown in the URL refers to the *Hive service principal* for which you need a **Kerberos service ticket**. There is no need to declare the "principal" for your login, it is already defined *implicitly* by your **Kerberos TGT** created by `kinit`.

Comment: That is the answer! Thx @SamsonScharfrichter   :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For beeline, the principal param in '!connect' must be hive@domainname, but who you are and what you can do in hive is controlled by the kerberos' tgt ,which is assigned by kinit.